# Is there a way to change cell text color without using code in excel?

Tags: excel

I need this:

I have some names and numbers in multiple cells and wanna merge them into a single cell, but I want to change only phone numbers' colors to red. Also, I don't want to use any macro or VBA codes. Is there a way to do this?

Here's a sample

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: No, you need VBA for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid VBA and macros, you can do the task manually:

1. in **C1** enter the formula `=A1 & CHAR(10) & B1`
2. format **C1** with wrap on
3. copy **C1** and pasteSpecialValue back onto **C1**
4. in the *Formula Bar*, hi-light the number part and apply the desired formatting

Repeat steps 1 through 4 for each pair of cells in columns **A** and **B**.

*(the advantage to using VBA/macros is that the macro will do all this work for you)*

Comment: Well I guess technically you can do it without a macro lol... Only I would never :-)